# Scroll pagination (search system), Jquery. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, scroll, pagination

Does anyone know any  scroll pagination system with data search system?
I tried to adapt the scrollpagination.js but I didn't get.
a tutorial or something that could help me?
Example .. Upon entering the site, the pagination would run normal but when someone does a search, it would make the paging according to the data entered.
I would like some tutorial on how to do this in jQuery or some plugin
Thanks and sorry my english XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in the past by setting up the API to accept the page-number and the results-per-page as parameters, then using jQuery i do an

`$.get('url?page=2&resultsPerPage=10', function(data){ appendResults(data) });`

I trigger this on scroll when it reaches the bottom.

Comment: I managed to do that, but what I'm looking for is how to search for results, such as "Horse, Animals" and make the standard paging ^^

Comment: That should all be handled by the back-end API and simply passing the search term in as a parameter as well.